# zero length read from file

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, posix

I have two processes, one of which is writing (appending) to a file, the other is reading from it.  Both processes are running concurrently, but do not communicate.  Another reader process may start before the writer process has finished.

This approach works, but read() often returns having read zero bytes with no error.  They ratio of zero length reads to non-zero length reads is high, which is inefficient.

Is there any way around this?  This is on POSIX filesystems.

Comment: This was the reason the inventors of UNIX developed the `pipe`.  Reading zero bytes is the normal *end of file* detecting mechanism in all UNIX systems, so you can use a named pipe instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a communication channel, there's no guaranteed method to prevent zero-byte reads or even long periods of hanging without reading any data when reading a file that is actively being written.  The Linux implementation of `tail` uses `inotify` to effectively create a communication channel and obtain information about the file write activity.

It's an interesting enough problem to that IBM has even [published a Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp3945.pdf) describing an implementation that was able to do such "read-behind-write" at about 15 GB/sec:

> Read-behind-write is a technique used by some high-end customers to
>   lower latency and improve performance. The read-behind-write technique
>   means that once the writer starts to write, the reader will
>   immediately trail behind to read; the idea is to overlap the write
>   time with read time. This concept is beneficial on machines with slow
>   I/O performance. For a high I/O throughput machine such as pSeries
>   690, it may be worth considering first writing the entire file out in
>   parallel and then reading the data back in parallel.
>
> There are many ways that read-behind-write can be implemented. In the
>   scheme implemented by Xdd, after the writer writes one record, it will
>   wait for the reader to read that record before the writer can proceed.
>   Although this scheme keeps the writer and reader in sync just one
>   record apart, it takes system time to do the locking and
>   synchronization between writer and reader.
>
> If one does not care about how many records that a reader lags behind
>   the writer, then one can implement a scheme for the writer to stream
>   down the writes as fast as possible. The writer can update a global
>   variable after a certain number of records are written. The reader can
>   then pull the global variable to find out how many records it has to
>   read.

Without a communications channel, you're pretty much left having to keep trying, perhaps calling `sleep()` or something similar after a number of zero-byte `read()` results.