# Parsing a running log

Tags: java, multithreading, parsing

I need to parse a running log. The log usually contains about 1.2-1.3 million lines a day.

What is the best approach for parsing the log real time? I will be using Java for this implementation. Can anyone please suggest a method to read the log in real time as more and more entries are being added to the log?

Any help would be duly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *What is the best approach for parsing the log real time?* Don't use Java.  The Java abstractions from the native file open/read/write calls make reading data from a file being actively written almost impossible to do reliably.  Reading an actively-written file can be hard to do reliably with native C or C++ code.  It's much better to cause the log files to be partitioned and batch process the files as they get rotated.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: As much as I would like to, I am bound to use only Java for the implementation. So any help for finding something using Java would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whoever is *requiring* you to use Java to solve this problem literally has no idea what he's doing. What you're trying to do won't even work reliably with low-level native `open()` and `read()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319031/zero-length-read-from-file

Answer (score 3):

Please specify what kind of logs would you like to parse, and how would like to use them.

---

Personally I can advice you to use [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) and [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), but all depends on what you want to achieve.
(in those apps you can make maps and groups of use)