# If I flush after every write, do no partial writes happen?

Tags: linux, file, io, buffer, flush

I have two Linux processes, `Reader` and `Writer`. `Writer` writes records one by one, and reader reads them. If `Writer` flushes after every write, is `Reader` guaranteed to see only complete records?

If not, is there any way to guarantee that `Reader` will only see complete records?

I assume this is an OS / filesystem question, but if language matters, I would be interested in the answers for C++ and Python.

Comment: I think the short answer is that a file is the wrong tool for the job. That's what databases are made for.

But if you want to go down this road: the 'standard solution' for atomic writes is to write to a temporary file, flush and fsync, then rename the file. The reader will have to re-open the file on each read.

(You not only have to flush the file but also fsync it at a minimum. flush, in Python at least, just flushes Python's buffers, it doesn't flush the OS buffers to disk.)

Comment: I mostly agree, and we're using a DB for this right now. I'm hoping to get better performance with flat files though. I really just want to store binary blobs in write order and read them back.

Comment: To guarantee atomic writes, you must ensure that each call to `write` does not try to write more than PIPE_BUF bytes at a time.

Comment: Using a file for this is absolutely horrible.  There's no way to control what comes out the other end. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319031/zero-length-read-from-file for an example (which this is really a duplicate of). Even if you guarantee atomic writes, you can in no way control what the reader sees, or what it might read.  *Can* you get better performance with flat files? Yes, but you have to engineer your entire stack - hardware and software. You'd be better served with a lot of RAM and a memory-based filesystem, or a fast SSD and do as @jbch says - rename the file when done.

Comment: Are they arbitrary binary blobs? If you could have a separator between records you wouldn't have to care about atomicity, you could just read until you hit the separator. But to do that you have to have guarantee that the separator will never appear in the middle of your blob.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If we're going to do this in memory I would just skip the filesystem and use a named pipe (if there's just one reader and writer). Much simpler and faster.

Comment: @jbch - but then the write process can block.